# org-mode - (require 'org-publish) causes downgrade in org-version

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have just upgraded org-mode to the latest available in ELPA. According to the official documentation, the installation has to be done in fresh emacs session where no org-related scripts/files have been loaded. The installation is successful, and `org-version` reports that I have updated to 8.2.6 (from 7.9.3f). However, as soon as I put back my old org-related scripts, and reload emacs, I'd get 7.9.3f when I run `org-version`. To track what's causing it I retrace my steps by adding my org-related scripts one by one. I found out that when I add back `(require 'org-publish)`, the version downgrades to the built-in one. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: The export backends in Org version 8 were refactored to be more modular. If you change to `(require 'ox-publish)`, does that fix the problem?

Comment: I've tried that already but emacs says `ox-publish` can't be found.

Comment: I was having a lot of issues when using org-mode from ELPA then I make an installation directly form the .zip file and it just works, have you tried that already?

Comment: I've provided my own answer to this question, see if you can discover something from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was primarily due to the way my emacs initializes (initialization script).

- In the latest version of org (8.2.6 at the time of writing), `org-publish` is now `ox-publish`, so I needed to call `(require 'ox-publish')` instead. I think calling `org-publish` or any older version modules causes the confusion in the setup.
- However, after changing the reference, I got an error about `ox-publish` not being found.
- To trace the problem further, I removed all org-related scripts from my `init.el` (that's how I named my initialization script), and run emacs again. When I ran `org-version` that time, I saw that it's 8.2.6.
- To check if `ox-publish` is getting loaded, I used the scratch buffer, and executed `(require 'ox-publish')` manually; it returned fine, confirming that the module was actually loaded. This means that `ox-publish` is only getting loaded after initialization.
- My first work around was to load my org publishing script after initialization using the `after-init-hook`:

  ```
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda() (load-file "/path/to/org-publish-project.el")))
  ```
- That solved the problem, and I could see my org installation upgraded correctly. However, I didn't feel good about loading the script through `after-init-hook`. Some people in the official orgmode mailing list suggested that I should check if I'm calling `(package-initialize)` in my `init.el`. I didn't. The operation loads the packages installed through the package manager. If it's not specified in the init script, it will be called after initialization by default. Learning that, I added a call to `(package-initialize)` somewhere at the beginning of my `init.el`. Afterwards, I called `load-file` to my org publishing script directly.

  ```
  (load-file "/path/to/org-publish-project.el")
  ```